# Ipywidget "Select" does not trigger callback on mouse selection

Tags: jupyter-lab, ipywidgets

In Jupyterlab when selecting a new value in the Select-widget using the mouse, the callback does not trigger.

When assigning a new value using code, the callback is triggered.

Expected behaviour:
clicking on/selecting a new value with the mouse should trigger the callback.

Example:

```
from ipywidgets import Select

# callback
def cb(change):
    print(change)

# widget
s_w = Select(value=None, options=['a','b'])
s_w.observe(cb, names='value')
```

```
s_w
```

Clicking on a or b triggers nothing:
but assigning triggers the callback and the print function.

```
s_w.value = 'a'
```

{'name': 'value', 'old': 'b', 'new': 'a', 'owner': Select(options=('a', 'b'), value='a'), 'type': 'change'}

How do I trigger the callback on mouse selection?

ipywidgets-version: 7.5.1
jupyter_client-version: 6.1.2

Comment: In Jupyter Notebook the example works as expected. Appears to be an issue with Jupyter Lab.

Comment: In Jupyterlab it mouse click works when using interact instead of observe. interact(cb, change=s_w);